# Android Studio sends data to server using volley, javascript error in responce

Tags: javascript, php, android, android-studio, android-volley

I want to send data to server using volley in Android Studio. I have a simple PHP server to handle requests, but when I send a request from my Android app, my application receives this:

```html
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" >
</script>
<script>
function toNumbers(d){
var e=[];
d.replace(/(..)/g,function)(parseInt(d,16))});
return e
}
function toHex(){
for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)
e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);
return e.toLowerCase()
}
var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("237c325ea260389e3d95c3d89e1b53dd");
document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+";expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT;
path="";
location.href="http://mywebsite/index.php?i=1";
</script>
<noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

my MainActivity.java code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button btnGetCode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetCode);
    btnGetCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Requesting new Code...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            syncCode();
        }
    });
}
public void syncCode() {
    String url = "http://mywebsite/index.php";
    final String code = "564814";
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            editText.setText(s.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            editText.setText(volleyError.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Code", code);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(request);
    queue.start();
}
```

I expect my server to return `'f'` or `'s'`, but it doesn't, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: So what's the question? StackOverflow does not work this way. Provide something you've tried and errors or the unexpected you're getting.

Comment: yes you're right, sorry. I expect server return 'f' or 's' to me. but it does not.